# Which select SQL query will be faster: the sorted or unsorted one?

Tags: sql-server

If i fires a query like this

**CASE A :**

**i :)**

```
select * from visitors
     order by visitdate desc
```

**ii:)**

```
select top 100 * from visitors
order by visitdate desc
```

**CASE B:**

**i:)**

```
select * from visitors
```

**ii:)**

```
select top 100 * from visitors
```

**EDIT 1:**

Which will be faster in case A i or ii in case B: i or ii

in terms of **CPU uses**(Computational time) and first output delivery
not Complete output delivery to client

**EDIT 2:**
I assumes its not indexed

Comment: I don't see a difference between the two sets..

Comment: So you are asking if it is faster to fetch 100 rows instead of fetching **all** rows? I think that depends on how many rows there are in the table.

Comment: yes but i am talking about the computational time

Comment: For Case A, option #2 will be faster **IF** you have an index on `visitdate`. For Case B, option #2 is **invalid** since you should never have a `TOP ..` without a `ORDER BY` clause - you want the first 100 rows - but you're not saying what the rows should be ordered by ..... you'll just get random data. But option B - #2 will also be faster, provided the table actually does have more than 100 rows.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that mean. You can use `set statistics time on` and have a look at the `CPU time`. It is dependent on how many rows you return.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson : yes you're right but when i did the same using remote database it take time for select * it's because data transportation time in local both take time 0.00s so i'm unable to distinguish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost all cases, **ii** will be faster, albeit not by much

Comment: this is a very vague "answer"

Comment: 1. **i** will get all rows and thus will always be slower when using IO (moving data to screen or over the network.
2. **ii** can use logic (depending on implementation of SQL backend) to do a quicker sort than full reading of the table

Comment: @Srdjan Grubor: "can use logic" - is vague as well. If it is not indexed - it will be fullscan with some logN sorting, if it is indexed - the index will be read. What's the logic in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have more than 100 visitors, ii will be faster.

As to the `order by` clause, it depends if you have an index on that field.